# Is there a way to set custom keypress aliases?

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts

Is there a way to bind aliases like <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd>+<kbd>h</kbd>  = <kbd>Home</kbd>? Or <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd>+<kbd>j</kbd> = <kbd>⇦</kbd>?  On my PC I am using a Vortex poker 3 keyboard that has this and many others as the function layer and I want to use is on my Linux notebook too. 
Any help is greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score -1):

Try using this : 
System Settings > Keyboard > Shortcuts > Custom